# International youth meeting

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, language

The following youths participate at the international youth meeting:

- John from the USA, 14 years old
- Pierre from France, 13 years old
- Stefan from Germany, 15 years old
- Marten from the Netherlands, 11 years old
- Ding from China, 12 years old
- Alberto from Spain, 15 years old

John says: there are four **teenagers** among us. Marten responds: that is not correct.

How many teenagers are there? How did Marten count?

Comment: In the future, please do not use exclusively male characters. We need to overcome our biases that make male the default and female an add-on trait.

Comment: @GregMartin I was trying to come up with names that belong to the respective languages, feel free to change a few of them.

Comment: While I agree that it's great to vary genders, if only for the sake of variety, I don't think it's inherently bad to have a collection of only one gender, be it male or female. There are a number of valid reasons one might have for doing so—there might be a clue in the fact that there are only men, it might be a misdirect, it might be part of the solution, etc. Moreover, on a principle level, inclusion in art should be a goal that's generally aspired to and laudable, but not a mandate/quota: it risks turning it into merely a box to tick, cheapening both itself and inclusion everywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Marten counted using

> the most widely spoken language of each participant's country, counting someone as a teenager if their age falls into the group of numbers between 11-20 that are represented using a form of the number ten in that language.

Based on this,

> John (four*teen* in English) is a teenager
>  Pierre (treize in French) is not
>  Stefan (funf*zehn* in German) is a teenager
>  Marten (elf in Dutch) is not
>  Ding (*shí*èr in Mandarin Chinese) is a teenager
>  Alberto (quince in Spanish) is not

So Marten thinks there are

> three teenagers.